# How to set the tablayout icon size for tablets

Tags: java, android, icons

How to set the tab icon size for tablets I did a lot of research, tried a lot of methods, but couldn't adapt it to my layout. The phone screens are normal but the "7" "10" icon sizes on the tablet screen remain very small.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();
```

I get icons programmatically.

```
}

private void setupTabIcons() {

    TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabOne.setText(R.string.Scanner);
    tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_image, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);


    TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabTwo.setText(R.string.Create);
    tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.create, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

    TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabThree.setText(R.string.History);
    tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_history, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);

    TextView tabFour = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabFour.setText(R.string.Settings);
    tabFour.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_settings, 0, 0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setCustomView(tabFour);

}
```

}

**my activity_main layout**

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_45sdp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**custom_tab layout**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textColor="@color/custom_tabtext1"
android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can support tablet using 3 way.

First way to create 3 layout file for tablet supports :-

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

Second way to create 3 dimension file for tablet supports :-

```
values/dimens.xml              # For handsets (smaller than 600dp)
values-sw600dp/dimens.xml      # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
values-sw720dp/dimens.xml      # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

Third way to using "Sdp" library for tablet supports :-

https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: My icon layout cannot be done as you said because main_activity.xml is not. I draw icons programmatically in the main_activity class, so creating a different screen size in xml doesn't work. Thanks for your answer. Is there a programmatic solution?